# Entity Framework (Code First) one to many - generates extra fields instead of using mapped keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, composite-key

I am attempting to get some nested data using Fluent API and .Include(). The database I am working with is not normalised, and I do not have control over it.

"Parent" table is TASK, and "child" table is STOCK_MOVEMENT, with a "many stock movements to one task" relation.

The mapping is supposed to be from TASK, with its composite key { "TSK_SITE", "TSK_TYPE" } onto STOCK_MOVEMENT, with its composite key { "MOV_SITE", "MOV_TYPE", "MOV_MOVE" }.

The [article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620.aspx) seemed to be most appropriate to my task at hand, particularly the "Configuring a Composite Foreign Key" section. Unfortunately, I don't seem to get the expected fields prompted by my intellisense for the "HasForeignKey" line, so I had to try something else... (thoughts welcome!)

What I tried instead is this:

```
            this.HasRequired(sm => sm.TestTask)
            .WithMany(t => t.Movements)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("MOV_SITE", "MOV_TYPE"));
```

Tried both "HasRequired" and "HasOptional"... However, the SQL that ultimately gets generated by EF contains extra fields instead of mapping against the Foreign Key that I have specified.

Can anybody explain how I should change my mappings in order to get correct SQL, please?
Guiding questions are also very welcome.

I am attaching all the relevant code below...

Many thanks!

Victoria

```
public class TestTask : IMyObject
{
    public TestTask()
    {
        this.KeyFields = new string[] { "Site", "TaskType" };

        this.Movements = new HashSet<TestMovement>();
    }

    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string TaskType { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public virtual HashSet<TestMovement> Movements { get; set; }

    //... more code
}

internal partial class TestTask_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestTask>
{
    public TestTask_Mapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.Site, t.TaskType });

        this.ToTable("TASK");

        this.Property(t => t.Site)
            .HasColumnName("TSK_SITE")
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.TaskType)
            .HasColumnName("TSK_TYPE")
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Key)
            .HasColumnName("TSK_REF");
    }
}

public class TestMovement : IMyObject
{
    public TestMovement()
    {
        this.KeyFields = new string[] { "Site", "MoveType" };
    }

    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string MoveType { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public virtual TestTask TestTask { get; set; }

    // ... more code
}

public class TestStockMovement_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestMovement>
{
    public TestStockMovement_Mapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.Site, t.MoveType });

        this.HasRequired(sm => sm.TestTask)
            .WithMany(t => t.Movements)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("MOV_SITE", "MOV_TYPE"));

        this.Property(t => t.Site)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.MoveType)
            .IsRequired();

        this.ToTable("STOCK_MOVEMENT");

        //this.Property(t => t.Site).HasColumnName("MOV_SITE");
        //this.Property(t => t.MoveType).HasColumnName("MOV_TYPE");
        this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("MOV_MOVE");

    }
}

// In DbContext...

public DbSet<TestTask> TestTasks { get; set; }
public DbSet<TestMovement> TestStockMovements { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestTask_Mapping());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestStockMovement_Mapping());
}

// In the appropriate method in the repository ...

IQueryable<TestTask> testTasks = context.TestTasks.Include(t => t.Movements);

// Where testTasks results in the SQL with incorrect foreign key field references 
// (please see the picture that tells a thousand words below)...
```

[image: Incorrect foreign key mapped by EF]

---

To clarify on the database fields and tables involved: I only mentioned columns used as keys to simplify the problem:

1) "TASK" table contains columns "TSK_SITE" and "TSK_TYPE", which constitute its composite key (+ more columns).

2) "STOCK_MOVEMENT" table contains columns "MOV_SITE", "MOVE_TYPE" and "MOV_MOVE", which constitute part of its composite key (+ more columns).. I have not used "MOV_MOVE" in my mapping, as there is no equivalent column in the parent TASK table.

I am expected to retrieve one or more STOCK_MOVEMENT records per TASK record.

Comment: If `{ "MOV_SITE", "MOV_TYPE" }` is your primary key in `STOCK_MOVEMENT` table what is then the foreign key to the `TASK` table? It can't be `{ "MOV_SITE", "MOV_TYPE" }` again (as your mapping says) if the relationship is one-to-many. If PK and FK is identical this could only be a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Many thanks for responding to my question, Slauma! I've added an edit to my original post, clarifying that there is one more column in STOCK_MOVEMENT table which is part of the composite key for that table, but which I have not added to the mapped relationship. There is no equivalent to that column in the parent TASK table, and so nothing to map to. How can I (should I) account for that column in my code to create a one-to-many?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping of `TestTask` seems correct. For the mapping of `TestMovement` you must map the full key with all three parts:

```
this.HasKey(t => new { t.Site, t.MoveType, t.Key });
```

Then map the column names and set all three key properties to *required* (key columns can't be nullable):

```
this.Property(t => t.Site)
    .HasColumnName("MOV_SITE")
    .IsRequired();

this.Property(t => t.MoveType)
    .HasColumnName("MOV_TYPE")
    .IsRequired();

this.Property(t => t.Key)
    .HasColumnName("MOV_MOVE")
    .IsRequired();
```

Then - most important - don't use `MapKey` for your relationship mapping because your foreign key columns are properties in the model class. In that case you always *must* use `HasForeignKey`:

```
this.HasRequired(sm => sm.TestTask)
    .WithMany(t => t.Movements)
    .HasForeignKey(t => new { t.Site, t.MoveType });
```

I know that you said that for `HasForeignKey` Intellisense didn't offer the expected properties (but does the code compile anyway?). That's another problem you need to solve. But using `MapKey` is no solution and doesn't bring you nowhere for your model and mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions, Slauma, I'll try them out in a few hours...

Comment: Have started "from scratch" and now the intellisense is working and your advice is spot on! Thank you for your help, everything works!